# How to properly use generic in Python classes

Tags: python, class, generics

I was wondering if there is a way to initialize a generic class like `self.my_generic = T()` below in python

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T') # assume that T can only be GenericA or GenericB

class BaseClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_generic = T() # This is what I want to achieve, but this won't work

class GenericA():...
class GenericB():...

# Usage
objA = BaseClass[GenericA]()
objB = BaseClass[GenericB]()
```

Apparently, the code above does not work. I'm not sure what `BaseClass[GenericA]()` does. I thought it would work as in C#: `BaseClass<GenericA> objA = new BaseClass<GenericA>();` but it doesn't:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

When using `BaseClass[GenericA]()`, would the `GenericA` class be passed somewhere to the `BaseClass` that we can reference to?

Answer (score -1):

There aren't generics per se in Python.  It uses duck typing so there is not real need for it.  Any data type can be given as function parameter so you could say all functions are genericv by default.

Comment: I know that I can define an init function like `__init__(sellf, T)` and use it like `objA = BaseClass(T=GenericA)`, but it's kinda ugly and I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it. Then I found out how people do typing in python and the square bracket in `BaseClass[GenericA]()`, but I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: This looks like a class where the author implemented the class level option of __getattrib__ to produce a class factory.  It's all just trickery, there's no generic feature underneath any of that.